# How to make amp-img not include text from <p> tag

Tags: php, amp-html

There are two versions of the page, amp and non amp. In the version without amp, the layout of the text looks like this

```html
<p><img src="https://www.example-site.ru/files/12345.jpg" alt="" width="30" height="30"> Some text for example. </p>
```

In the version with amp, the layout becomes like this

```html
<p>
  <amp-img layout="responsive" width="1280" height="768" src="https://www.example-site.ru/files/12345.jpg" alt="" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout">
    <i-amphtml-sizer style="padding-top: 60%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>Some text for example <img decoding="async" alt="" src="https://www.example-site.ru/files/12345.jpg" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
</p>
```

Due to the fact that the amp-img tag included text, it is not displayed when viewing the amp page, because it is under the picture. How can this be avoided?

One tag is changed to the other by the usual function [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php), no additional manipulations are performed.

`$this->content = str_ireplace("<img", "<amp-img layout='responsive' width='1280' height='768' ", $this->content);`

Comment: check the the image tag close for amp-img

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. And `<amp-img>` does not include text by default. You can check your implementation from [AMP-Playground](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/source/).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `<img>`, which is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element), `<amp-img>` is a container and needs to always be explicitly closed with `</amp-img>`.

Therefore, the `str_ireplace` call you have will result in the text being inside `<amp-img>`, i.e. `<amp-img src="...">Some text for example.</amp-img>`, making it a child of `<amp-img>`. Since it's neither a fallback nor a placeholder, this child of `<amp-img>` simply won't be rendered.

It's hard to suggest a solution without knowing more about other transformations you're applying, but I recommend rethinking your approach and ensuring `<img>` tags are replaced with `<amp-img>` tags that are properly closed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please make clear, which information can help you to suggest a solution? Maybe some piece of code? I just doesn't know how to find end of an img tag with `preg_replace` to add there close tag for amp-img.. or with `strpos`...